# How install ttf font locally a font avoiding the use of woff version

Tags: css

My question should be strange but it has it's own sense.

My web browser is not compatible with woff format, and is not Internet explorer but a modified version of IE for sure.

This web browser is running by an hmi application based on TIA Portal (siemens), with this browser I need to look, using siemens web browser, an html page generated by one vision system.

This video system is using an icon font in woff format, and is not compatible with my web browser.

My idea was that to convert the font in ttf and install it locally on pc, but this don't work on my pc and olso in the hmi (hmi is running a windows 7 embedded version) and I don't understand why it doesn't work in each pc!

the css generated by the sensor is this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'fontello';
src: url('fontello.eot?60611638');
src: url('fontello.eot?60611638#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fontello.wof?60611638') format('woff'),
    url('fontello.svg?60611638#fontello') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Obviously i cannot change the generated html.

Why the browser don't use the font converted and installed locally??

Answer (score 0):

Your `@font-face` rule is missing a .ttf url, as well as a `local` reference
Try this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: local('fontello'),
    url('fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fontello.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fontello.woff') format('woff'),
    font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

See also: [MDN Docs: @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#description)

Comment: How I explained, the web page is generate by an industrial Vision System, I cannot change the css and I cannot change the firmware and I don't think they will never add this "feature", what I don't understand is why browser don't get the font if is installed on Windows